# How to switch user in Linux with password

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap

I have client with LDAP authenticatation, when user1 login to client, and switch to user2 (sudo su - user2), he just login without password.
I want to make switching user in client with authentication password from ldap, how can I do that?
Thanks for help.

Comment: have you added "NOPASSWD:" for the users in /etc/sudoers.

Comment: With *which* password?  user1, or user2's?

Answer (score 0):

Use `login <username>` to get a login prompt.